# How to change data source names in Google Data Studio

Tags: data, sql, tools, google, google-data-studio

Google Data Studio has connectors to MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. but these connections will come with default names.

Couldn't find out how to set the names for data sources in Google Data Studio. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not obvious but if you go resource>manage added data sources>edit action on source and then simply click the connection name it's actually a text box and you can rename it there.

Comment: thanks. The Google team as usual making an effort for developing the least possible user friendly products...